# Swipe action on android

Tags: android, gesture

Referring to [these tutorials and examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11532921/1951418), I tried to implement the swipe action. For that, I wrote below codes in onCreate method of MainActivity.

```
ActivitySwipeDetector swipe = new ActivitySwipeDetector(this, null);
RelativeLayout swipe_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainll);
swipe_layout.setOnTouchListener(swipe);
```

Now I have few questions -

1. is passing null as SwipeInterface activity is okay?
2. What is the use of SwipeInterface activity argument in ActivitySwipeDetector class? Is it okay if I just implement all functions inside ActivitySwipeDetector class, deleting SwipeInterface class?

Thanks for help as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Okay never mind, I think I got it ..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SwipeInterface {
    public static int CURR_BOOK_ID = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActivitySwipeDetector swipe = new ActivitySwipeDetector(this, (SwipeInterface) this);
        RelativeLayout swipe_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainll);
        swipe_layout.setOnTouchListener(swipe);
    }
......................
....................
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a NullPointerException inside onRightToLeftSwipe and onLeftToRightSwipe because of the lines `activity.onRightToLeft(v);` and `activity.onLeftToRight(v);`. You can either implement everything in `ActivitySwipeDetector` class and get rid of those lines (but it's not a good solution) or implement on your own activity, mark this activity as `implements SwipeInterface` and pass `this` as second argument to `ActivitySwipeDetector`.